# how to reset counter when looking for a sequence of strings properly

Tags: python

so i am doing the cs50 dna problem and i am having a hard time with the counter as i don't know how to code to properly count the highest amount of times the sequence i am looking for has repeated without another sequence in between the two. for example i am looking for the sequence AAT and the text is AATDHDHDTKSDHAATAAT so the highest amount should be two as the last two sequence is AAT and there is no sequence between them.

here is my code:

```
text="TCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGACTTGTCGCTGACTCCGAGAAGATCCTAACATTAACCAATTCCCCCTAGTCTGAGGCACGGTTACCGATCGGGTTAATGGATCTCTCACCGTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAAACGTGTAACTGTAATAATCCGCCCGAAAAAACTGATCTTAGGGTTGCGGCATCTGCACGTGACAGTGTGCTACTGTTAGATAGAGGGATCAAACGAGGTTGCAAGGATTATATCTCTCCGTGCTCGATAAGACACAGCCGGTTGCGGGCTGCTTCCTCTGGATCCAATGCAGCCGTACGTACACCGTAGAGCAAATTTAGTGGTAAAGGAACTTGCTCAAACACTACGGCTTCGGGCTACTGTTGGCGCCGGTTGGGGATCCCATTCAACGCTGGCCCTTTCGCTATGGTTCGGTGATTTTACACCGAAGCGAACCTTGAACCGTGGATTTCGGGTGTCCTCCGTTTTTAGGTACTGCGTGCAGACATGGGCACCTGCCATAGTGCGATCAGCCAGAATCCATTGTATGGGAGTTGGACTCGTTTGAATTTACCGGAAACCTCATGCTTGGTCTGTAGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGAAACTGGGCGACTTGAAGTCGGCTTGCGTATTAATAGCTCTGCAATGTAACTCGGCCCTTGGCGGCGGGCAGCTTAGTATTGAACCGCGACACACCATAGGTGCGGCAAATATTAAAAGTACGCTCGAACCGGAACCTGTCTCCATGACTGGACGACCAGCCCGGCGTCTTCTACGTAACACAGGGGGCTGTCGAGGTAGGGCGTAGGAACTTCGGGGTCACTACGCCGTAACAGCACCGAATATCATATCATCCAACTTGCTTGGTACATGCCCCGTTCTGTATCAAAAGTTTACGGCCCCGGACATACCTGCTGTCAGTTGAATACCTATGCGAGTCTGAAACACGAATAGTTCAGGCGTGCAAAGACACGCTAAGCACACGCCGCAGGCAGGGGGGGTATTTTATAAGTCGTTTTTTGGAAGGGTAATGTAAACTTATCCCATAATACCCTTTGGCTTCCCCTCACTCGTGCACTTCTCATAATGATACGTCAGGGTGATTGTAGATTCACGCGTCATCAGATTGTCCCTTTCTCGAGTCTTAGTATCTTTCCTAATCCGCTCGACTCTGCGCCATGATCGAATTCCTGACAGGCTACAAGAATAAACTGCCAGCATACTCCTTACCGATTGGCGCCTACTAATTATACGCACATGGGCATCTTCGACGTCTAAACATAGGCTCTTAGTATTCCGTAGGATGTTGAGCCGACAGGAAAGTCAAACGTCGTGGGTGACCGTAGCCTGACTCGCCCGACGCAGGATTCGCTCATATGTGTGAACGGATGCTTATGTAACTTCCTAATTGCAGCGAATGGCAGTTCCGTAGTGAAGGTTCGAAACGTACGGGGTCCGGCCATGGATTAGATCTTTCAGTGCGCTAAACTCTTAACCGCAGATACTTGGCGGACCATCTTCGTGTTGCTACTATGGTATAGACCAGGCTGTCGAATCTACTTAACACAGGTGAACCCCCAGATCGGCTAGAGCCTTCGAGGCTAGACCTTTAACAATCTTTAGACACTTCCAAATCGCGGCCGGATATGTCTCGTTGGCAGCCGCAGACAAGAGAAGAGGGTCGGCAGTGTCTGCCACGCGTGACCTGTATGATCTTAGCCTTTAAGATCACACTACTGATCACAATCTATTATGATTGCCTTAGCTAACTGAGTGATGCACCCCCACAGGCTGAGAGAAATCTGTAGTTTGACGACACGCCGTCTGGCTAAAAATGTGAATCCGCCGATCCGAGACGGTGGAAGCTTGAGACCAAATGCGGGAAACCAATGACTTCATTACGGAACAAGACATAACGGCGTGAGTTGACGACTGGGATTAACCCTTTCCCGAGTCTGTACTTCTGCTACACAATGAGGATGCGAATTATCTAAGACCTTGTACTACCTAAACTAACCCTGAGGCGGGCATTGAATTCCGGCCATCTTCAGCCCAAAGAAAGACCAAATGTGAGGAAAATGAGGGATCGGTATAAGCTTTTCACGATCTCAAGGTTCACGGCCGCCAGGGCCGTAGTTGGGGCTTCATGCACATTGCCAACCCGGACATCGACAGTCGGTACCGCAGGGGTTCGAGGAATACTCCCAGCTGTGACACCTGGTCGTCGACTGGACCCAGCTGGTGGGCGGCATAGGTAGTTAATACTGAATTAAAGCCGGGAACGTCTCTCTAACTAGAAACCTTGTGATAGGATACACAGACCTAGTGCCCCGACGTTAGCATTTGAATTCATCTATCTTGGCGTCTTTTAGTAGGCCTGGGTCAACTCCGGCGTTGGCCAAAATAACCGATCTGCGTTATGTGGCCACGCATCGAGTGACAGGGTGCATACAAATTGATGGTCAAAGAGTTTAAACAAGACAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCCCCACGCTTCTACATAGCCACACTGGAGCTAGTCCTCGTGTTAAATTTTTCGCTTGTTGCACGGTTATCATCAGAAGTGCCACTGGTATTCCTCTGTAGCTCCCGTATGCCGAAGGTTGCGGCTTAGGTACTGCTTATACACGTCTCTCAAGTTTGTCAGCCGCGTGATCTTTCTGCGGGGATAGGTGATCGTCCCTCGCTCCGGACATTGCATTAAAATTACCTAGTTGATAGGGCGGCGGAGTTGCATACCGGCGTTCAATCGCGGCTCCAGACTGGTTTGAGCTACGCGTCTGCCAGCGTGAAAAAGCTGATTTGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCCAGGTATTATCATTTGAATCGTATGTTTTCTGCCGTACGTCAACTGCGTCGTCGGGGACTGAAATGGTCTGCCTCCAGACCCTTACCTCCCGATAAGCCATGACTAAGTATGTGAAGGATCACCTGAATTGCTGAAAGTTAACGGTAAGATATCTGAAAGAGCTCATTAGATCCAACACTTATCTACTCAAAAATTCGTCATATTTCGGTGACTTGCTAGAAAGGCTCTTGCACAGTAAGGTTATAGAGAATGCTACCGTTGAAGCACCAGCCGTTGAAGCCCGCCTTTAACCACGCGATATATCCAATTAACCAAGGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGTCGCCTTGTAATAATTACTTTGGCCCGGATTATAACGAAGGAACTCGCCATGAACTCGCAGCACGTTGTACTGGAACAATCTACTTTTTATAATATAGCGATAACTCCCAGCTTTTATGTGGGTGATATTGTCCTAGCTTTTTAAAGATACCCTCTGGCCCGGTCCAAGTAAGGTCCACATTGCCTGACGTAAGCGTACGGTCAACGGGTGCACCGGTTCCCGCTAAAGCTCGATCCTATTCTTTCAGTCGGGGGGAAATAAACTCGTATACTCTCCACCCACCCGTACGTCCCGGACTAGAATAACTACCGGGTATTTCCGGTTCGTAACACCACGCCATGACGTGTCAACATAAACGCTTCTTTTGAAAGGTGCACATGCAGATTGCACAAGCAGCAGGCACCGCCCTTATCCATATCCTGTTGAGGCCCTCGATCCTAGTGTTCCTTGTTATCAGGATATTTTCTCGCTGTACGTTATTGTCCTTTTCAAATTACAACTGACCGCTTCCTCACCCGCTAAACCCTACCTTACGCACAACCAAGGCCTTGTCCCGGATGAACCCGGCTGCTCCTATGGATAAGCAACCCAGCCCGGCAGTTTACTTCAGGTGTTATCGTCGACTGACACCCTCAGCTTTCTCCCATTACACAGCGAGTATTTTCCGCGTAGCAATGGCAGTGACTTTGAGCGCACACTCAGAAGCCGTTGGAATGGCACCGGGGACGGCCCGATTTAGCCCCGCACACCTCCTGGAATCTTAGATCGCACGGCGATCTCGGTTCAGGCACCAACCCCAAAGAGTGTTTTGAGTTTTTGGTATGGCTCGCCTCAATTATCGGTTTTCGCTGCTCTGTGCCTGTCAACTCGGCTAGCTGTCGTGTTTTGTCGATCAGTGCGTGGACACTCTCGGTCGATGGTCGTGGATGGGACTGTAGTAAGTTTCACCGAAGCAGGAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAACTTCGCTTCATATAACGTAGCCATAGTGCTGTCTGCCATCAATAAGTCTTGCTCAGTGGTGCATACGTCGGGGAGGTTTGTTCCGCCTGGTCAGAACGAGTCTAGGGCGAGCCTATAGGCCAGTCGAGAGCCAAGATTCTATGAAATTAATACGACTACTGGGTGAGAGGTCATACAATTCCCGTGGAATCTGTACCTAAGATATTTCCAGATAGGGATGGCTACTGGTTAAGTTGACAGTGTCTAGATACGTGAGAGCACCTGAGAGGACGCCACGAGTCGGAGCGTGGGCGATCACCCTTCTGAGTCATAAGTCATGTCTATATATCCCTCACTAAAAAGGGCACACGACTATACATGCTTGAGCTTTACGGTCTGGCATGTGGAATGCCCGGAGCAACCCAGTCTTACCATCCTTTACGTACATTTACCGACCCGGCAGTGGCCGGCGCGGAAACCCAGGAGAACGTCGGTCATGATACGCGCCCTCCGCCGAAAGCGTGCTCACACCTCAGGATATCAGCGCTATTACCGGACGTCCCGCGTCCACCATCTAATAATTCAGGTGCTCCTAATAAGTGGGCTGGAGAGCGAGGATTGATATACGTTGAGGAGCTCCGACGGCCCTCTCGTGCGTTTGATGTAGATTGCGTTACCGACGGAGCACGCGTTTGTCAATTTCTGTCTAGGGACGTTTATGTCCTCAATACGAATACCAGGCCTATTTTAGTGTACAAATCACTTAGCAGTCGGAATTGGAAACCTGATGGAAGCGT"
counter=0
length=len(text)
search="AGATC"
tmp=0
for i in range(length):
    if text[i:i + len(search)] == search:
        tmp += 1
        if tmp > counter:
            counter = tmp
    if text[i:i + len(search)] != search:
        tmp = 0


print("done")
print(counter)
```

Comment: A regular expression is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, the `regex` solution is the Python way to solve this.  However, if you want *your* code repaired ...

The problem with your code is that your index fails to acknowledge that you've found a match.  You have no way to recognize consecutive occurrences.

Consider the case where you've found the start of a triple-match, `AATAATAAT`.  You get to the first `A`, recognize, the `AAT` and increment `tmp`.  You go to the next loop iteration, and now `i` points at the second `A`.  You see that it's *not* `AAT` here (it's `ATA`, spanning the first two occurrences), so you record one instance and reset all your status variables.

Instead, you have to jump to the end of the first match and look for a second.  Since your index does *not* move smoothly by increments of 1, you'll want a `while` loop instead.

> Please learn to use meaningful variable names where the variables have
> any meaning.  `i` is fine if *all* it does is to manage your loop.  As
> soon as you use it for anything else, give it a real name.  Similarly,
> `tmp` and `count` *really* need replacing.

```
snip_size = len(search)
pos = 0      # position in the genetic sequence
rep = 0      # number of consecutive repetitions
max_rep = 0  # longest repetition sequence found

while pos < length:
    if text[pos:pos + snip_size] == search:
        rep += 1
        pos += snip_size
    else:
        max_rep = max(max_rep, rep)
        rep = 0
        pos += 1

print(max_rep, "repetitions found")
```

Output:

```
15 repetitions found
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```py
import re
sequence = "AATDHDHDTKSDHAATAAT"
matches = re.findall(r'(?:AAT)+', sequence)
largest = max(matches, key=len)
print(len(largest)//len('AAT'))
```

basically this way will find you the list of substrings in the string you are have then you choose the largest substring. The number of occurrences of the substring will be the length of the largest divide by the length of substring